# Multiple Result Rows into Single Row

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 4 tables: Stores, Terminals, StoreTerminals, and Address.  In reality, each Store has multiple Terminals but only a single Address, so I'm trying to get results that basically show one Store per row with multiple Terminals and the single Address.  My attempts at joining these tables produces multiple rows for the same Store :(

The records in the StoreTerminals table just has a StoreID and a TerminalID, so if a Store has more than one TerminalId then there are multiple records.

I saw another question where group concatenation came close to what I wanted but that would leave the results for multiple Terminals in the same column, which I do not want.  I need each Terminal to be in it's own column.

Does anyone know how to accomplish this?

Comment: you need dynamic pivot

Answer (score 1):

You should look at pivot feature in Sql server. This should let you result one column for one terminal.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/spike/archive/2009/03/03/pivot-tables-in-sql-server-a-simple-sample.aspx

Answer (score 1):

It sounds to me you need to pivot your data.

Store Id, Store Address, Terminal id 1, Terminal id 2, etc.

Here is a link to the pivot command.  It turns rows into columns.  The unpivot command is the reverse.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx